# Impact of removing Dragonborn from Khorvaire

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-3.5e, eberron

I plan on running an `Eberron` campaign and may end up doing it in 4th ed, but am interested in preserving the story of 3.5 `Eberron`. IMO `Dragonborn` should not be common in `Khorvaire` and would be at best exclusively something out of `Argonnessen`. Would their be any major impact in the books if I removed the presence of `Dragonborn` altogether from `Khorvaire`, or will key characters in the new world be removed?

For extra credit: Would their be any other confusions if I tried to run `Eberron` in a 3.5 style story but give the players the 4th ed books?

Comment: For an answer to your second question, this question might be helpful: [What changed in Eberron between 3.5e and 4e?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10113/what-changed-in-eberron-between-3-5e-and-4e)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No.**

Although 4E's `Eberron` campaign setting makes an effort to include all the new races and classes from the new edition, the `Dragonborn` are not given a role of special prominence, or even much of a plot thread of their own.

Removing them would be easy.