# Travel to Aerenal from Khorvarie (Eberron intercontinental travel)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, eberron, maps, travel

I can't seem to find a map that gives me distances to and from Aerenal and Khorvarie, nor a set cost. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The various maps of Khorvaire, like [this one](http://sancus.off.net/khorvaire_complete.jpg), put the southern tip of Valenar just over 200 miles from the northern coast of Aerenal. Pylas Maradal is the nearest port to that point, so that could be another hundred miles or so assuming you don’t want to ship out from the far end of the “jungle of scimitars” Ravar Orioth. The map of Aerenal in *Eberron Campaign Setting*, [here](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/eberron/images/d/d5/Aerenal.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070827010926), puts Pylas Talaear nearly 300 miles from the northern tip of Aerenal.

However, it is *blatantly obvious* that these two maps are not consistently scaled. The tip of Aerenal found in the first map is much, much smaller at that map’s scale than it is in the *Eberron Campaign Setting* Aerenal map. And this is because *Wizards of the Coast badly messed up the scales on Eberron maps*. This is a known, admitted fact. The original distances were too large at least a factor of 10, for the populations described in the text (or else even the most vibrant and fertile lands of Khorvaire have population densities rivaled by some deserts in the real world). And here we see considerable inconsistencies of scale.

Assuming we go with that factor of 10, that puts Pylas Talaear something like 30 miles from the northern tip. The original 300-400 miles from the other map also seems suspect, but it’s harder to say exactly what it is; I suspect it is more than 30-40 miles. But really, Pylas Maradal and Pylas Talaear don’t seem all that far apart, which seems consistent with the ancient Aereni expeditionary force to Khorvaire that forms the basis for Valenar’s modern claim.

Beyond these, little and less is offered. *Explorer’s Handbook* offers this tidbit on page 97:

> From Sharn, the journey to Seren is almost 4,000 miles [...] In a sailing ship, the journey takes half a year or more [...] In a House Lyrandar airship or elemental-bound galleon, the trip can be completed in four weeks. **Pylas Talaer in Aerenal, a popular layover port, is approximately halfways between Sharn and Seren.**

This implies three months by traditional ship, two weeks by something elemental-fueled, but that’s coming from Sharn, a great deal further away than Pylas Maradal. The first map would call it approximately 1000 miles more, but this contradicts the statement that Sharn to Pylas Talaear is half of the 4,000 miles from Sharn to Seren however, since by the map it’s certainly less than 1,500 miles.

Frustratingly, *Explorer’s Handbook* actually discusses travel within Aerenal (specifically from Pylas Talaear to Shae Mordai), but not about getting to Pylas Talaer in the first place, aside from the off-hand mention as part of the Sharn to Seren trip.

As far as costs, *Explorer’s Handbook* has a table of various costs on page 18. Assuming you’re only transporting a party and you’re not chartering your own trip but just renting a place on a ship making the journey anyway (i.e. almost certainly the Sharn–Pylas Talaear trip unless someone has ties with the Valenar), you’re looking at approximately 1300 gp per person on an airship, about 400 gp per person on an elemental galleon, and about 40 gp per person on a regular sailing ship. Various other options are also documented. Ships of any stripe probably don’t go to Aerenal very often, though; you could be waiting several days or weeks to actually have one of these options. Chartering your own is vastly more expensive.

Comment: What would be your expert recommendation for the best Eberron map to use for a globetrotting campaign?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I have never seriously had cause to establish exactly how long it would taken to travel from place to place; it was always just hand-waved. So I mostly just ignore the scales on the maps, knowing that they’re rarely useful and having little need for them.

Comment: Do you know anything about—as mentioned in [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/10114/8610)—the *4E* maps being rescaled? (I know this question's tagged *3.5E*, but maybe *4E* has maps that are better?)

Comment: @HeyICanChan Unfortunately, no, I know nothing about what 4e did with Eberron’s maps. After I learned only a little bit about what 4e did with Eberron as a whole, I became entirely disinterested. Maybe that is one area in which the 4e Eberron is better.